# Jquery hover caption

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover, caption

i have several div's in my html code.
[position 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHIlK.png)

when i hover this div's first div is hovering, but other div's don't.

[position 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5OSc.png)

This is my html code :

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="main_discover_img_wrapper">
    <img src="imgs/photo-21086277.jpg" id="main_discover_img"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" id="photo_details_main">
        <h4>Photo author Name</h4>
        <p id="photo_details_p">Flowers in my brain!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="main_discover_img_wrapper">
    <img src="imgs/photo-21086277.jpg" id="main_discover_img"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" id="photo_details_main">
        <h4>Photo author Name</h4>
        <p id="photo_details_p">Flowers in my brain!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#main_discover_img_wrapper{
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}
#main_discover_img{
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}
#photo_details_main{
    background-color: green;
    color:black;
    float: left;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    width: 99.2%;
}
#photo_details_p{
    display: none;
}
```

This is my java script code:

```
$("#main_discover_img_wrapper").hover(function(){
    $("#photo_details_p").fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $('#photo_details_p').fadeOut(500);
});
```

I want hover all div's. not only first. Can you help me?

Comment: id must be unique change to classes .. elements with same Id just work with the first one .. so each element should has his unique id .. use class=""  instead of id=""  you can have more elements with same class  and in js code use  .  for class  instead of   #  for id

Comment: Read this before asking a question : http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; http://jsfiddle.net/gxm9sb6p/6/

id in any programming language should be an **unique** identifier. In HTML do not give multiple elements the same id. Anytime you find yourself giving the same id to multiple elements, consider using a class instead.

I have changed your html/css/javascript to change your ids into classes. The new javascript function wait for the document (the content of the page) to be ready before binding hover event, and looks for the child of the hover-ed element with `find()` to apply animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main_discover_img_wrapper").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".photo_details_p").fadeIn();
  }, function(){
      $(this).find(".photo_details_p").fadeOut(500);
  });  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1st: as I said don't duplicate your id so your code should be something like this

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="main_discover_img_wrapper1">
    <img src="imgs/photo-21086277.jpg" id="main_discover_img1"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" id="photo_details_main1">
        <h4>Photo author Name</h4>
        <p id="photo_details_p1">Flowers in my brain!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="main_discover_img_wrapper2">
    <img src="imgs/photo-21086277.jpg" id="main_discover_img2"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" id="photo_details_main2">
        <h4>Photo author Name</h4>
        <p id="photo_details_p2">Flowers in my brain!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in js

```
$("div[class^='col-md-'][id^='main_discover_img_wrapper']").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("p").fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).find("p").fadeOut(500);
});
```

> Note: js code above may work even if you do not change Ids .. but Id
>   must be unique

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fpt02tnv/)

Comment: @vakhtangpataraia you're welcome .. but I recommend to read about [selectors](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)  to know what is the meaning of ^=  ... Good Luck :)  .. and don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you .. Thanks :)

Comment: @vakhtangpataraia sorry my bad you should use .find('p')  instead of .find('img')  .. updated answer  .. and I think it will be better to use slideDown()   and slideUp()  instead of  fadeIn()  and fadeOut()